# Project with Firebase UI does not build

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I'm trying to use [Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) in my Android project

When I add the necessary compile statement in the `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
```

the project does not compile any more and I keep getting the following messages:

[image: gradle build errors]

My build.gradle dependencies section is:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
```

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312558/android-dependency-error-compile-com-android-supportappcompat-v726) does not help me further.

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter, regards

Comment: Congratulations! You can make an answer instead editing your question. Hence you will help the community ;)

Comment: I'm so sorry about that: thanks for your suggestion, I will do it!

Answer (score 1):

I would click on each link that says, "Install repository and sync project". You don't have a couple the required tools installed, primarily the`com.android.support:support-v4`. This different than the app-compat verision you have in there.

Comment: I clicked already: Android Studio lets me wait for a while and then does nothing, no matter which link I click on.

Comment: @user1737538 I would recommend checking your SDK manager to make sure that the appropriate frameworks are downloaded. it may also be downloading in the background

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Firebase Auth And Database dependencies to this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
```

So as mentioned in the docs you need version 11.0.4 of Firebase Services for 2.3.0 FirebaseUI Version

Also check [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies) table and upgrade or downgrade your dependencies depending on it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion: unfortunately gradle build error is still there.

Comment: Have you added  Google's Maven Repository in project level gradle file?

Comment: Already done, thanks.

Comment: Downgrade your Build Version to 25 and check

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Novo Lukas' suggestion, now the project builds correctly. The problem was the **maven entry** in the **build.gradle** project file: I added the

```
maven { url  'https://maven.google.com' }
```

line only to the `repositories` branch, but not to the `allprojects`. Adding that line to the `allprojects` too did the magic.

Thanks to all, regards

Comment: You can mark this as answer to close the question :).